# Gathering multiple elements and on enter, trigger a click on which ever is selected

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying to accomplish:

When a user tabs over and hits enter on any labels present in my application (the months or percentage labels), it simulates a click on whichever label you're on.

Here's the JS code:

```
///////// Accessibility

// Grab label ID's for labels

const allLabels = document.querySelectorAll("labels");

// On hitting enter of any month or percentage label, trigger a click

allLabels.addEventListener("keyup", onEnter);

function onEnter(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    allLabels.click();
  }
}
```

It currently throws an error of, "allLabels.addEventListener is not a function", and also of course doesn't work.

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) returns [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) not an element. 
So, you need to loop over all Element and add Event

```
const allLabels = document.querySelectorAll("label");
allLabels.forEach(label => label.addEventListener("keyup", onEnter));

function onEnter(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let currentLabel = e.target;     // e.target returns the label on which user press Enter
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    //allLabels.forEach(label=>label.click());
    currentLabel.click();

  }
}
```

**OR**

You can add Event to the Parent Element which contains all the label.

```
document.addEventListener("keyup",onEnter,true);

function onEnter(event) {
  let element = event.target;
  if(element.nodeName==="LABEL" && event.keyCode === 13) {        
    allLabels.forEach(label=>label.click());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Just tried both above, neither worked :(. Not sure if I'm implementing it incorrectly, I've updated my link above with your code. Is there anything I missed?

Comment: Replace const allLabels = document.querySelectorAll("labels"); with const allLabels = document.querySelectorAll("label");

Comment: sorry! Just noticed that when I tab and hover over any of the labels and hit enter, it automatically select 60 months and 50%.

I want it to only click on the individual label that the user hit enter on. Any idea how to do that with your code?

Answer (score 1):

The method `querySelectorAll` returns an **array of nodes** that match with the selector used. For that reason, you cannot call the `addEventListener` method over an array.

You need to iterate the array and bind the listener for each element:

```
const allLabels = document.querySelectorAll("labels");
Array.from(allLabels).forEach(label => label.addEventListener('keyup', onEnter))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
const allLabels = document.querySelectorAll("labels);
allLabels.forEach( label => {
 label.addEventListener('keyup', onEnter);
});
```